# Apache Geode server not restarting with xml SAXParseException

Tags: java, xml, geode

In the process of making a straightforward change to data in the region (cleared the region and re-loaded the new dataset). The data in the region had an updated class structure, so I updated the domain class / serializedID and repackaged the jar that I add to the the server classpath to help out with queries in pulse.

I have a simple setup, 1 locator 2 server/members

```
gfsh>list members
  Name   | Id
-------- | -------------------------------------------------
locator1 | 10.32.XX.XXX(locator1:11077:locator)<ec><v0>:1024
server1  | 10.32.XX.XXX(server1:21045)<v22>:1025
```

With a replicated persistent region:

```
gfsh>describe region --name=NPI
..........................................................
Name            : NPI
Data Policy     : persistent replicate
Hosting Members : server1

Non-Default Attributes Shared By Hosting Members  

 Type  |    Name     | Value
------ | ----------- | --------------------
Region | data-policy | PERSISTENT_REPLICATE
       | size        | 5069949
       | scope       | distributed-ack
```

I brought down sever2 when I tried to restart I got this error:

```
gfsh>start server --name=server2 --server-port=40412 --group=NPI_GRP --classpath /opt/app/proj/npidomain.jar
Starting a Geode Server in /opt/app/proj/server2...
The Cache Server process terminated unexpectedly with exit status 1. Please refer to the log file in /opt/app/proj/server2 for full details.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.geode.cache.CacheXmlException: Error while parsing XML, caused by org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 419; cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '1.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'cache' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '8.1'.
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.xmlcache.CacheXml.error(CacheXml.java:907)
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.xmlcache.CacheXmlParser$DefaultHandlerDelegate.error(CacheXmlParser.java:3613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:137)....
```

This is Apache Geode 1.0.0-incubating running on RHEL6 Java 1.8.0_101. Neither of these variables have change since the error started.

Not even sure where to start looking as very little changed between deployments.

Even though both gemfire and geode are installed on the same machine I am certain that I'm in the correct gfsh:

```
[geodeusr@hostname proj]$ ./gfsh
    _________________________     __
   / _____/ ______/ ______/ /____/ /
  / /  __/ /___  /_____  / _____  / 
 / /__/ / ____/  _____/ / /    / /  
/______/_/      /______/_/    /_/    1.0.0-incubating

Monitor and Manage Apache Geode (incubating)
gfsh>
```

Comment: Do you have both GemFire and Geode installed? It may be possible that gfsh is now trying to start GemFire rather than Geode. What is the version printed in the gfsh banner?

Comment: You might want to share the full log file of server2 and the contents of cache.xml on user@geode.apache.org

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kirk. Unfortunately a day after I needed to blow away the disk store and re-load from scratch. I no longer have the logs from that day (not that they were verbose or very useful). If this occurs again, I'll ping the mailing list.